# Changing view gradient background in real time

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gradient, layer

I am practicing with gradient backgrounds for a bigger app and created this dummy app to simplify the concept. The view has a 50/50 gradient background and 2 rows of colored buttons.

I want the user to be able to play with colors of the gradient by tapping upper and lower buttons, so that gradient background changes accordingly to buttons color.

[image]

ViewController's code is following:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var currentUpperColor = UIColor.black
        var currentLowerColor = UIColor.white

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
        }

        func setGradientBackground(lowerColor: UIColor, upperColor: UIColor) {

            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
            gradientLayer.colors = [lowerColor.cgColor, upperColor.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

            view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        }

        @IBAction func upperColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
            currentUpperColor = sender.backgroundColor!
            setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
        }

        @IBAction func lowerColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
            currentLowerColor = sender.backgroundColor!
            setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


}
```

But when the app runs, nothing happens when buttons are tapped. I understand some kind of view redraw should occur, but I'm not sure how to call it.

Comment: Have you tired `layoutSubviews` ?

Comment: I think you are every time inserting a new 'Sublayer' and thats why the UI doesn't change.

Comment: have you tried to _remove_ the previous gradient (=layout)? you just always insert a new gradient under the current one (in the z-level), of course it won't be visible because the other layer covers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Will always insert the gradient layer at index 0. Initially u created a layer with black and white color and added at position 0. Now when user chooses a new color you create a new layer and add it index 0 making black and white layer to be at index 1. Hence only black and white layer will always appear

**Solution:**

Remove old layer and add new layer.

**Step 1:**

Declare gradientLayer as instance variable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
     ....
 }
```

**Step 2:**

In IBAction remove old layer and add new layer

```
@IBAction func upperColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            currentUpperColor = sender.backgroundColor!
            setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
        }

        @IBAction func lowerColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            currentLowerColor = sender.backgroundColor!
            setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
        }
```

**Solution 2:(Not the preferred one)**

If you want to stack up layers with different colors (I don't personally see any reason for doing so, but if thats what you want then) you can use

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(CALayer(), at: UInt32(view.layer.sublayers?.count ?? 0))
```

So modify your `setGradientBackground` as

```
func setGradientBackground(lowerColor: UIColor, upperColor: UIColor) {

            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
            gradientLayer.colors = [lowerColor.cgColor, upperColor.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

            view.layer.insertSublayer(CALayer(), at: UInt32(view.layer.sublayers?.count ?? 0))

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I really don't need to stack up gradient layers, so your solution is very elegant and efficient)

Comment: @Denys Triasunov : am glad that the solution worked for u :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and here it seems found working with following changes:

```
import UIKit

class GradientController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var vwButtonContainer: UIView!

    var currentUpperColor = UIColor.black
    var currentLowerColor = UIColor.white
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
    }

    func setGradientBackground(lowerColor: UIColor, upperColor: UIColor) {

        if gradientLayer != nil {
           gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [lowerColor.cgColor, upperColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)


        let sublayersCount = view.layer.sublayers?.count ?? 0
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: UInt32(sublayersCount))

        view.layer.layoutSublayers()
        view.bringSubview(toFront: vwButtonContainer)


    }

    @IBAction func upperColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentUpperColor = sender.backgroundColor!
        setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
    }

    @IBAction func lowerColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentLowerColor = sender.backgroundColor!
        setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Storyboard Layout:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: there is something oddly beautiful about your final picture, its just....mezmerizing. good job though!

Answer (score 0):

The code shows that you have declared the CAGradientLayer() as a local variable. So it means that every time you want to update the button a gradientLayer gets inserted/ added to the view.
The layer must be added only once and the colors must be updated according to the button actions.

```
var currentUpperColor = UIColor.black
var currentLowerColor = UIColor.white
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setGradientBackground(lowerColor: currentLowerColor, upperColor: currentUpperColor)
}
func setGradientBackground(lowerColor: UIColor, upperColor: UIColor) {
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [lowerColor.cgColor, upperColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
@IBAction func upperColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    currentUpperColor = sender.backgroundColor!
    gradientLayer.colors = [currentLowerColor.cgColor, currentUpperColor.cgColor]
}
@IBAction func lowerColorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    currentLowerColor = sender.backgroundColor!
    gradientLayer.colors = [currentLowerColor.cgColor, currentUpperColor.cgColor]
}
```